# Symbol not found: curl_mime_init in macOS 10.3 (high Sierra.)

Tags: macos, curl, libcurl

I have built a .framework in mac using Xcode. In the framework i use  Libcurl, to handel APIs. One of the APIs uses curl_mime_init to send a file. This framework work perfectly fine in MacOS 10.15 and above. However if fails to work in MacOs lesser than 10.15.

While i make the file upload. i get the following error in the crash report.

```
Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _curl_mime_init
Referenced from: /Applications/Adobe InDesign 2020/*/BasicExternalObject.framework/BasicExternalObject (which was built for Mac OS X 11.3)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
```

I did some digging and found that curl version shipped on macOS 10.14 and lower has `curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1`   However `curl_mime_init` was Added  in version 7.56.0.

Later i updated my curl from 7.54 to 7.70 and still found the issue to persist.
I confirmed it by running `curl -V` and it was pointing to the  updated version
I am stuck here. Is there a way to solve this. Or does it have something to do with the OS.

Comment: You probably still link/use the old lib then and not the new...

Comment: @DanielStenberg i checked using curl -V . It was pointng to the latest. Is there something else i need to check to see if curl is linked properly

Comment: You need to update liburl, not curl. The latest is 7.80, not 7.70.